# How do I make a Slider for wordpress posts that can also contain Videos?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, slider, posts

I want my Wordpress Page to show a posts pictures and Videos in a slider. So I need a way to make a slider for each post. How should I do that?

Comment: Is plenty of sliders plugins out there, all you have to do is search. However Slide Revolution is a good one : )

Answer (score 0):

Good day.
My choice is slick-slider.
Check please website [Slick Slider official](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)
Run please the snippet and you can replace the images with your videos

```js
$(".slider").slick({
  dots: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slide: 'div',
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

```css
.slider{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.image img{
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
    height: 55%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h2>Slider demo</h2>
<div class="slider fade">
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>  <div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```